# Keep formatting from Text PHP

Tags: php, text

i am having trouble keeping the format of what i input in a Text Area with this code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Make a new Paste
        </h1>
        <form method="post" action="pastenew.php">
            <div class="panel panel-success">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Paste Name" class="form-control input-title" value required>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <textarea rows="10" name="paste" placeholder="Insert your paste here" class="form-control input-paste" style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; height: 214px;" value required></textarea>
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit Paste</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="reset">Reset</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" style="font-size: 18px; text-align: center;">Still in development, come back later!</div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

When i press submit it opens a new page and everything where i have this to test if it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<?php echo $_POST["title"];?><br>
<?php echo $_POST["paste"];?>
</body>
</html>
```

But instead of getting the text formatted i get it all in one line. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Use `<pre>` tags around your output.

Comment: Use [`nl2br`](http://php.net/nl2br) or [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)

Comment: Alright that worked now i have a problem that if the paste is HTML or PHP or some web programming language it displays it instead of the text.

Comment: @user3241491 well, you cannot have both...

Comment: Now im having trouble with instad of text it displays the HTML eg: http://paste.devrosemberg.com/viewpaste?id=12 What can i do to display it as text?

Answer (score 1):

try using **nl2br()**

```
<?php echo nl2br($_POST["title"]); ?>
<?php echo nl2br($_POST["paste"];) ?>
```